GRPC io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: Keepalive failed. The connection is likely gone
I am new to grpc and java and trying to make use of grpc bidi streaming. I have a grpc server in javascript and client in java running android 7.1.1 version. I am trying to use bidi stream to communicate using between the client and the server using keepalive settings. When the android client initiate a request I send a metadata before any streaming calls. But after few seconds ( 5 to 10 ) it receives System.err: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE or System.err: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: Keepalive failed. The connection is likely gone even though the server is up and running. I also receive the server side end and cancelled events (have some logic based on these events). Sometimes these events are registered within a second.
I am not getting why this is happening.
I tried with this but it did not solve my problem.
Server side keepalive setting:
'grpc.keepalive_time_ms': 10_000,
'grpc.keepalive_timeout_ms': 5_000,
'grpc.keepalive_permit_without_calls': 1,
'grpc.http2.min_time_between_pings_ms': 5_000,
'grpc.http2.max_pings_without_data': 0,
'grpc.http2.max_ping_strikes': 1

Client side logic:
public class Generator {
    private final ManagedChannel channel;
    private final GRPC_SOCKET_SERVICEGrpc.GRPC_SOCKET_SERVICEStub asyncStub;
    CommandRequest req = null;
    StreamObserver<CommandRequest> requestObserver = null;
    public static Thread gRPCThread = null;

    private final String TAG = "GRPC_LOGGER_TAG";

    public Generator(String host, int port, String sm) {
        ManagedChannel channel = AndroidChannelBuilder.forAddress(Constants.BIDIRECTION_STREAM_DOMAIN, Constants.BIDIRECTION_STREAM_PORT)
                .usePlaintext()
                .keepAliveTime(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .keepAliveTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .keepAliveWithoutCalls(true)
                .build();
        this.channel = channel;
        asyncStub = GRPC_SOCKET_SERVICEGrpc.newStub(channel);
    }


    public void shutdown() {
        try {
            channel.shutdownNow().awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            Log.w(TAG, "Channel Shutdown Success for gRPC" );
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error shutting down channel: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void retryConnection(String sm) {
        try {
            Log.w(TAG, "Retrying to start the gRPC thread");
            Thread.sleep(10000); // Wait for 10 seconds
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        startStream(sm); // Restart the gRPC connection
        Log.w(TAG, "gRPC Thread started successfully");
    }

    public void sendMetadata(String sm) throws Exception {
        try{

            Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
            Metadata.Key<String> deviceIdentifierKey = Metadata.Key.of("device_identifier", Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER);
            metadata.put(deviceIdentifierKey, sm);

            GRPC_SOCKET_SERVICEGrpc.GRPC_SOCKET_SERVICEStub stubWithHeaders = MetadataUtils.attachHeaders(asyncStub, metadata);

            requestObserver = stubWithHeaders.commandProcessor(new StreamObserver<CommandResponse>() {

                @Override
                public void onNext(CommandResponse response) {
                    try{
                        // client logic
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error onNext : " + e.getMessage());
                    }

                }



                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable t) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error : " + t.toString());
                    shutdown();
                    retryConnection(sm);
                    t.printStackTrace();

                }

                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Stream Completed");
                }

            });
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e(TAG, "Error "+ e.getMessage());
        }


    }

    public static void startStream(String sensorManager) {
        gRPCThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{
                    Log.w("GRPC", "Attempting to connect with grpc server");
                    Generator generator = new Generator(Constants.BIDIRECTION_STREAM_DOMAIN, Constants.BIDIRECTION_STREAM_PORT, sensorManager);

                    generator.sendMetadata(sensorManager);
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    Log.w("GRPC", "Connected to gRPC server");
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e("GRPC", "Could not connect to grpc server : " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });

        gRPCThread.start();

    }

}


This question is similar to: UNAVAILABLE: Keepalive failed. The connection is likely gone. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Updated the question. Thanks!
